# how to map: :Conqueterm to :ctp (command-mode) not to (normal mode)

Tags: vim

I recently started using Conqueterm in gvim in fedora, it's lot of pain to type all that, so is there any way to map it to a shorter key
i need to have this map to command mode(ESC -> :ctp) rather than in normal mode(ctp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User  defined commands  must always  begin  with a  capital letter.  Lowercase
commands are only the built-in ones.  Anyway, you can create a shorter version
of your command by adding something like this to your *.vimrc*:

```
:command! Ctp ConqueTerm
```

Or add arguments to create an even more handy command:

```
:command! Ctb ConqueTerm bash
```

Another option is  to check your autocompletion settings, and  type `:Con` and
hit the  tab key. It should  autocomplete to the  full command. A map  is also
valid:

```
:cnoremap Ctp ConqueTerm
```

Or an abbreviation:

```
:cabbrev Ctp ConqueTerm
```

As you can  see there are multiple ways  of doing it. Each one  has its unique
aspect, though sometimes  you'll not notice in simple commands  like this one.
Pick up the one that works better for you.